# How can an Array be used as a property name?

Tags: javascript

How does this code work?

```
if (!(args in pad)) {
    pad[args] = self.apply(obj, arguments);
}
```

args is array, but shouldn't it be a string because it's a key of JS object?
How would check work? `array in object`?

Full context [here](http://talideon.com/weblog/2005/07/javascript-memoization.cfm):

```
Function.prototype.memoize = function() {
    var pad  = {};
    var self = this;
    var obj  = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[i] : null;

    var memoizedFn = function() {
        // Copy the arguments object into an array: allows it to be used as
        // a cache key.
        var args = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args[i] = arguments[i];
        }

        // Evaluate the memoized function if it hasn't been evaluated with
        // these arguments before.
        if (!(args in pad)) {
            pad[args] = self.apply(obj, arguments);
        }

        return pad[args];
    }

    memoizedFn.unmemoize = function() {
        return self;
    }

    return memoizedFn;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

args is converted to a string which for arrays means:

```
[1,2,3].toString() == "1,2,3"; //true
```

It is automatically converted to a string when used in `in`:

```
( [1,2,3] in ( {"1,2,3":""} ) ) //true
```

This happens because the `in` operator only accepts strings on the left side.

When you use `pad[args]`, the same conversion happens again because object keys can only be strings. For example, when you are using `array[1]`, what actually happens is `array["1"]` because the number is converted to a string.

Comment: but where is it casted? Does JS interpreter automatically by default tries to cast any args type  to string, when i use  pad[args]??

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Could you, please, explain  this line: var obj  = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[i] : null;  What does i refer to? I see no loop..

Comment: That means the function will not work when `arguments.length > 0`, because `i` is not a known variable in the scope and it will throw a `ReferenceError`. It would be worse if this function worked though ;)

Comment: Nit: There is no *casting* go on. The expressions are *coerced* (or *converted*) to strings. *Casting* generally implies the "view" changes while the "data" (object) does not.

Answer (score 3):

This should clear things up:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var s = "" + a
var x = {}
x[a] = "hello world"
alert(s in x)
```

That is, **property names are *always* strings and *are converted* to such *as needed***. (Note that "bare" objects will generally not work as property names because they lack an appropriate string-ification -- but see below for how `toString/valueOf` can be used.)

The [ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is really hairy to find "simple" things like this -- it is the most convoluted over-worded language specification I know about -- but it boils down to the various productions that accept property names (as expressions).

See section 11.2.1: Property Accessors

> The production MemberExpression : MemberExpression [ Expression ] is evaluated as follows:
>
> [...] 6. *Let propertyNameString be **ToString**(propertyNameValue)*.
>   [...] 8. *Return a value* [...] *whose referenced name is 
>   propertyNameString* [...]

And section 11.8.7: The in operator

> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression [aka propertyNameValue] in ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> [...] 6. *Return the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of rval with argument **ToString**(lval [aka propertyNameValue]).*

Now, the following chain occurs for determining the result of `ToString(propertyNameValue)` (please consult the specification for all the little details):

1. `ToString`, section 9.8
2. `ToPrimitive`, section 9.1
3. (For Objects) `[[DefaultValue]]` (with a "String" hint), section 8.12.8
4. (For Objects) Result of `toString()` or `valueOf()` (first callable one)

This same `ToString` process applies for *all* access to properties -- be it `obj[prop]` or `obj.HasOwnProperty(prop)` or `prop in obj`.

Happy coding.